# Lotka-Volterra equations: wrong solution

Tags: python, python-2.7, ode

I wrote a piece of code to solve the Lotka-Volterra equations using fourth order Runge-Kutta on Python but for some reason it doesn't work, the solution is completely wrong. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong to be honest.

```
import numpy
from pylab import plot, show


def rk(f, x, h):
    f_1 = f(x)
    f_2 = f(x+1./2*h*f_1)
    f_3 = f(x+1./2*h*f_2)
    f_4 = f(x+h*f_3)
    return x+1./6*h*(f_1+2*f_2+2*f_3+f_4)


def lv(x):
    alpha = 1.
    return numpy.array([alpha*x[0]-x[0]*x[1], x[0]*x[1]-x[1]], float)


a = 0.
b = 10.
m = 100
T = numpy.linspace(a, b, m)
H = (b-a)/m
X = numpy.zeros((m, 2))
X[0, :] = [1., 30.]

for i in range(1, m):
    X[i, :] = rk(lv, X[i-1, :], H)

plot(T, X)
show()
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: maybe just use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html

Comment: In what sense do you think that the result is wrong? Note that the step of your time discretization is `(b-a)/(m-1)`, check against `T[1]-T[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the integration interval to 100 and increase the number of steps accordingly to observe the periodic behavior of the solution, I get a period of about 34.6 with rather small peaks.

[image]

Think about it from an ecological point of view, you have a predator population of 30 and a prey population of 1, with noticeable predation. Of course the prey is rapidly reduced to near zero, then the predators starve also to zero, and from that the prey population slowly recovers until its exponential growth triggers an exponential growth of the predators, and the cycle starts from anew.

---

Note that the step of your time discretization is `(b-a)/(m-1)`, check against `T[1]-T[0]`. To get `m` intervals with step size `H=(b-a)/m` you need `T=linspace(a,b,m+1)` and increase the x array and integration loop accordingly.

Comment: I was getting weird results also with interval expanded to 10 and with different prey predator numbers, so I doubted my solution was right. Didn't even think of simply giving it even more time. Thank you!